# How to add className to body tag

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I am trying to do something like below in plotly

```
 <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/ico" />

  </head>

  <body class="nav-md">
  </body>
```

Specifically define `className` for body tag and add some meta info to head tag. Could anyone please help how can I accomplish the same.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you need to add a class to the body? There's only going to be one, so your CSS could just specify `body {}` with whatever styles you want to apply.

Answer (score 3):

> If your HTML content isn't static or if you would like to introspect or modify the templated variables, then you can override the Dash.interpolate_index method.

https://dash.plotly.com/external-resources

```
import dash
import dash_html_components as html


class CustomDash(dash.Dash):
    def interpolate_index(self, **kwargs):
        return """
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
            <head>
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
                <meta charset="utf-8">
                <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
                <link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/ico" />
            </head>
            <body class='nav-md'>
                {app_entry}
                {config}
                {scripts}
                {renderer}
            </body>
        </html>
        """.format(
            app_entry=kwargs["app_entry"],
            config=kwargs["config"],
            scripts=kwargs["scripts"],
            renderer=kwargs["renderer"],
        )


app = CustomDash()

app.layout = html.P("Hello World")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: Thanks, i really didn't want to create an assetd folder just to modify the background color!